# sys.stdout.write does not grep

Tags: python, grep

I have a python script that writes to a screen as a startup script. I want to monitor the progress of the server so I go into a loop checking the status. I don't want to write down the screen. Therefore I'm using sys.stdout.write. The issue is that the program I'm using (wlst Weblogic) prints all this logging which I don't want to display. I get around this by using grep and only printing lines that start with a space.

I have this function

```
def printRoll():
   print ' Is my Print working'
   myTest = ' Hello'
   myTest1 = 'test 123'
   sys.stdout.write("\r %s " % myTest)
   sys.stdout.flush()
   systime.sleep(10)
   sys.stdout.write("\r  %s " % myTest1)
   sys.stdout.flush()
   systime.sleep(10)
```

What I want to display is:

```
 Is my Print working
 Hello
```

then after 10 seconds Hello is over written with

```
 test 123
```

if I run the grep command

```
python 'printRoll()' | grep '^[[:space:]]\{1\}[A-Za-z0-9]' --line-buffered
```

it only prints the first line

```
Is my Print working
```

It wont print any of the sys.stdout.write lines. I think it is an issue with the buffering but I can't find an example for my issue.

The python script works as expected but it also includes lots of other info I don't want to print to screen.

Any help appreciated.

I believe it is an old version of Python, i.e. 2.7

cheers
James

Comment: With `\r` you are printing carriage return characters which is not a newline on UNIX. You should use `\n` to print a newline. However, if you want to do logging, and in particular log some messages to stdout and others to a file, you should look into using the standard [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module in Python.

Comment: I don't want a new line I want to replace the line. I assume this means grep will not work, any ideas how I can get this functionality?

I just tried this code as a test and the stdout still did not print

    def printRoll():
   print ' Is my Print working'
   myTest = ' Hello'
   myTest1 = 'test 123'
   sys.stdout.write("\n %s " % myTest)
   #sys.stdout.flush()
   systime.sleep(10)
   sys.stdout.write("\n  %s " % myTest1)

Comment: Commands like grep are line-oriented. In fact `--line-buffered` in particular means it won't output anything until it sees a newline. If you want to clear and rewrite messages in place but only want to display certain messages I would recommend using an option to set a verbosity level.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is the other lines aren't new *lines* as far as `grep` is concerned, as you are not outputting a `\n` newline character.

What grep sees is – this output is via `xxd` for a hex dump so we can see all the characters – the following. `0a` (on the second line in the dump) is the newline character. You can see that there are no more newline characters (`0a`s) after that, so there's nothing more for `grep` to slice the input to lines on.

```
00000000: 2049 7320 6d79 2050 7269 6e74 2077 6f72   Is my Print wor
00000010: 6b69 6e67 0a0d 2020 4865 6c6c 6f20 0d20  king..  Hello . 
00000020: 2074 6573 7420 3132 3320                  test 123
```